# can web application get user saved file location

Tags: web-applications

I have a web application  that let the user open pdf file in a new window .

when the window is opened it ask the user if he wants to save/open the file .

I need to know the location the user had saved the pdf , is threre a way the application will know this saved file path ?

Answer (score 0):

No. The file is returned in a separate request and the browser handles the saving of the file. There is no ability to intercept this action or get the browser to report the result.

Imagine the user cancelled the save, for example. How would the browser know to tell your web application that information?

Comment: can you please explain what exactly happen when user save/open a file that the server send by using window.open (aservlet is copying the file to the httpResponse of the new window).

Comment: When a browser requests a file (any file HTML or otherwise) it first looks at the MIME Type of the response. This tells the browser what is inside the file. If it understands the file it will open it automatically. If it doesn't, it will ask the user to save the file. Once the user selects a location, the browser just saves the contents of the request to that location. It does not tell your server where it saved it or if it saved it at all. You can start a request and throw away what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

From the web server you will not be able to read where user has saved his file (nor whether he saved it at all).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the client side filesystem via a web-browser.

The browser acts as a barrier between the server (who might not be trustworthy) and the client (the user who might not want his private information published).

There can and must be no way for this to work and there never will (or at least should since it exposes client data that could be used for example to accurately guess the users Operating System which would lead him open to automated attacks).